# Closures get parent function name

Tags: bash, closures, lexical-closures

Bash is “kind of function programming language” it dose not have classes. I
managed to use encapsulation with [Closures](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), but I want also to do some
introspection to find also `docker_` parent/super/base function (If you know add
comments to define this correctly).

I managed this but with a dirty hack `super=${FUNCNAME}`. Is there any solution
to use kind of `PARENT_FUNCNAME`? I have such file *docker_.sh*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
function docker_ {
    local super=${FUNCNAME}
    function hello {
        echo "INFO" "do ${super}${FUNCNAME}"
    }
    function install {
        echo "INFO" "do ${super}${FUNCNAME}"
        #sudo curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh || exit 1
    }
    function run {
        echo "INFO" "do ${super}${FUNCNAME}"
        #docker run -d -p 3306:3306 ${DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME} /docker.sh run_mysql
    }
    ${@}
}
${@}
```

Got some results:

```
$ ./docker_.sh docker_ hello
INFO do docker_hello

$ ./docker_.sh docker_ run
INFO do docker_run

$ ./docker_.sh docker_ install
INFO do docker_install
```

## Solved

use

```
${FUNCNAME[1]}
${FUNCNAME[@]:0:${#FUNCNAME[@]}-1} get all list beside main
```

code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
function docker_ {
    function hello {
        echo "INFO" "do ${FUNCNAME[1]} ${FUNCNAME}"
    }
    function install {
        echo "INFO" "do > ${FUNCNAME[@]:0:${#FUNCNAME[@]}-1} "
        #sudo curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh || exit 1
    }
    function run {
        echo "INFO" "do > ${FUNCNAME[@]:0:${#FUNCNAME[@]}-1} "
        #docker run -d -p 3306:3306 ${DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME} /docker.sh run_mysql
    }
    ${@}
}
${@}
```

Got some results:

```
    ➜ ./docker_.sh docker_ hello  
    INFO do docker_ hello
    ➜ ./docker_.sh docker_ install
    INFO do > install docker_ 
    ➜ ./docker_.sh docker_ run    
    INFO do > run docker_
```

Comment: Thanks, i was looking for how to get the parent function that calls a function, from without that child function.  Works great!  `${FUNCNAME[1]}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash really isn't a functional programming language. To start with, functions are not first-class objects; you cannot pass a function around. You can pass around the *name* of a function, but it's just a name; if the name is given a new value, then the old value is lost.

Bash does not have lexical scoping: bash scoping is dynamic. The `local` command is a command, like any other command. It is not syntactic. If it is not executed, the name is not made local. For example:

```
f() {
  if [[ $1 == local ]]; then local myvar=local; fi
  myvar=changed
}

$ var=original
$ f local
$ echo $myvar
original
$ f global
$ echo $myvar
changed
```

And bash does not have closures. You can define a function inside a function, but the function so defined does not carry the scope with it.

```
$ g() {
>   local myvar=inner
>    f() { echo $myvar; }
>    f
> }
$ myvar=outer
$ g
inner
$ f
outer
$ h() { local myvar=inside_h; f; }
$ h
inside_h
$ f
outer
```

Comment: for @rici
1. I did not ask about what is "local";
2. I did not receive answer to "Is there any solution to use kind of PARENT_FUNCNAME"

Comment: @andrei Because it has no answer. There is no parent scope because bash doesnt really have scopes. If your question is, "can I find the name of the caller?" then ask that. But there is no way to find the name of the function in which the current function was defined, and the solution you propose won't work for reasons I tried to explain.

Comment: Ok, then I ask. @riki can I find the name of the caller? from "./docker_.sh docker_    hello" to get caller name "docker_" ?

Comment: @andrei: `${FUNCNAME[1]}`